# Garabage collection error on a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the following `DataTable`. While i am trying to add rows to this data table it returns an error like this

> Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point
>   where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is
>   optimized.

Does the `DataTable` has any memory limits?

```
dtOrder = new DataTable();
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sl_Odr_ID", typeof(long)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pack_dtl_ID", typeof(int)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Batch_No", typeof(string)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Qty", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_free", typeof(int)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Rate", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Gross", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Discount", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_DisPerc", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Asses_Amt", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Ex_Duty", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_tax_amt", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_FreeQty_Tax", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Asses_Amt_onFree", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Net_Amt", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales_Cess_on_KVAT", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("edu_cess", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hedu_cess", typeof(decimal)));
    dtOrder.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("tot", typeof(decimal)));
```

Comment: Are you having this error while debugging because I've only seen that error in the context of debugging something?

Comment: Sounds more like a [threading issue](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Cannot+evaluate+expression+because+a+thread+is+stopped+at+a+point+where+garbage+collection+is+impossible%2C+possibly+because+the+code+is+optimized.) to me.

Comment: Did you try with a Clean build, i suspect you were making intermittent changes and something got messed up due to that

Comment: Oh come on Marco I JUST fixed the formatting on the question :(

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: Yes jesus. On debugging.It is inserted into DB, but shows this error. It is not there if any of the decimal column in changed into integer..Do you know why?

Comment: @Nithesh, what are the access modifiers of your dtOrder object and are you sharing it between threads? If not then make sure you don't have optimize code selected in the build options for your project.

Comment: @Jesus:actually i wrote that on info class as public property; like public DatatTable dtOdr{get{ table creation;}}. And used a method for adding rows and i called that function in my UI.

Comment: But can multiple Threads access it? If so make it volatile.

Comment: @Jesus:No. A single thread is using that

Comment: Do you have any event handlers for OnTableNewRow or OnRowChanging etc that might be doing something untoward?